# How to get Tweet ID from tweet event

Tags: javascript, twitter, dom-events

I am using the [Twitter web-intents / javascript API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events), and I'm a bit surprised. What I'd like to do is listen for an event after a tweet occurs. Following their example:

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
    // Do something there
});
```

However, what I'd like to do is store the tweet id, or some other relevant information. If I take a look at the `event` object, there doesn't appear to be any relevant information in the `data` attribute.

**Is it possible to obtain the tweet ID (or any other details about the tweet) by listening to a tweet event?**

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I only receive a null value for event.data

Comment: As stated in the comment to ascii-lime's answer, the `data` value is null. I have not had any luck with this :(

Comment: Seems like the event.data.user_id is only populated on "follow" event, I couldn't find an answer for your question, did you?

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone know the answer?

Comment: Same problem here, data is always null :`(

Comment: Some related posts: https://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=2356 https://twittercommunity.com/t/using-the-tweet-button-and-web-intents-is-there-a-way-to-find-out-the-new-tweet-id/16990/3 https://twittercommunity.com/t/web-intents-event-callback-has-data-null/18595

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Web Intent events exist as a mechanism to trigger functionality in your page, not a data API.](https://twittercommunity.com/t/examples-of-capturing-web-intent-events/21448)

> The tweet event gets fired to indicate that a Tweet has happened, but
>   we don't provide identifying information through the event payload:
>   Intents function on your site without a user authorizing you access to
>   their account, and providing a Tweet ID for an anonymous user's action
>   would implicitly provide you with their identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tweet id you can use twitter's streaming API where they provide almost all the details with regards to a tweet.

But this has a catch as you will need to know the hashtag or at-least a part of the content of the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

As Xeno as cited, you're not able to get such information from the Browser JS Widget from Twitter. The Event Bindings are only intended to the following purpose:

> By adding listeners to the actions users perform in Web Intents, you
>   can trigger functionality in your app, or send (anonymous) data about
>   those events to your web analytics system (like Google Analytics,
>   Omniture, or your own analytics engine.)

So basically, you're able to do something within your app after the user has tweeted something.

At this JSBin (http://jsbin.com/nalexuwuhi/1/) I've just created a basic test, where you're able to see the whole event object. The "tweet_id" value is only intended to "say" twitter to which tweet you're responding, e.g. the parent tweet and not what the tweet_id of the create tweet is. I think for such purpose you have to use the twitter api and therefore some server-side coding.